# PostgreSQL : ERROR: syntax error at or near "("

Tags: python, postgresql

I started to learn PSQL. I have a question how to solve this problem, in my opinion the code should be ok but BD says otherwise ;). Can someone help me with this. Thank you in advance.

The code is from a terminal on Ubuntu (this is the method I want to create the table), not from pgAdmin.

```
exercises_db=# CREATE TABLE* product (
exercises_db(# id serial, 
exercises_db(# name varchar(32),
exercises_db(# description text,
exercises_db(# price decimal(5,2),
exercises_db(# PRIMARY KEY(id)
exercises_db(# );


ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: CREATE DATABASE product (
```

*Errata: I already changed in the example, I did not notice that I was doing instead of "TABLE", "DATABASE". Again, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The SQL is fine; your attempt to assign it to a shell variable is not.

Comment: Type `psql` at the shell prompt, then type SQL at the pSQL prompt.

Comment: There is "shell" code, Python and SQL, all using similar but effectively different syntax. To add to this, you can embed each into the other for various purposes. Chances are that you fed code for one into the other. From your description, it's not really clear what you did. For example, it's not even clear what part of the above is code you wrote and what is output the code generated. You can [edit] your Q to clarify that. Please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    id serial primary key, 
    name varchar(32),
    description text,
    price decimal(5,2)
);
```

Comment: Thank you, this code works fine, so when can I use PRIMARY KEY at the end?

Comment: The error was caused because you tried to create a database instead of a table, the query will also run fine if you add the PRIMARY KEY at the end I merely added it at the beginning as it is my personally preferred syntax.

Comment: @MrCoin, you use `PRIMARY KEY` at the end if you want the PK to cover more then one field.